# Unable to parse data in dhtmlx grid on Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, xml-parsing

I'm using DhtmlGrid to parse data, it run good on IE, but can not run on Chrome and FF, when I debug I see it seem can not parse data from Dhtml grid.

this is my file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/test_style.css">
<link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="../../dhtmlxGrid/codebase/dhtmlxgrid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../dhtmlxGrid/codebase/skins/dhtmlxgrid_dhx_web.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../dhtmlxGrid/codebase/dhtmlxcommon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../dhtmlxGrid/codebase/dhtmlxgrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../dhtmlxGrid/codebase/dhtmlxgridcell.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var qlist1_grid;
var qlist2_grid;
var qlist1_json = {};
qlist1_json.rows = [];
var qlist2_json = {};
qlist2_json.rows = [];

function qlist1_init_qlist_grid() {
    qlist1_grid = new dhtmlXGridObject('qlist1_grid');
    qlist1_grid.setImagePath("../../dhtmlxGrid/codebase/imgs/");
    qlist1_grid.setHeader("Q Code,Q Type,Difficulty,Allotting,Question");
    qlist1_grid.setInitWidths("100,80,80,80,750");
    qlist1_grid.setColAlign("center,center,center,center,left");
    qlist1_grid.setColTypes("ro,ro,ro,ro,ro");
    qlist1_grid.setColSorting("int,str,str,str,str");
    qlist1_grid.enableMultiselect(true);
    qlist1_grid.attachEvent("onRowSelect", function(){          
    });
    qlist1_grid.setStyle("text-align:center;", "","", "");
    qlist1_grid.setSkin("dhx_web");     
    qlist1_grid.init(); 
}

function qlist1_reload() {

    qlist1_grid.clearAll();
    qlist1_grid.parse(qlist1_json,"json");
    alert("run here-------");
}
...
<script>
```

this is error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
at window.(anonymous function)._insertRowAt (http://localhost:8080/QMTM_DEMO/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/dhtmlxgrid.js:725:65)
at window.(anonymous function).render_dataset (http://localhost:8080/QMTM_DEMO/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/dhtmlxgrid.js:671:197)
at window.(anonymous function)._process_json (http://localhost:8080/QMTM_DEMO/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/dhtmlxgrid.js:665:36)
at window.(anonymous function).parse (http://localhost:8080/QMTM_DEMO/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/dhtmlxgrid.js:617:178)
at qlist1_reload(http://localhost:8080/project/tmanager/exam/make_write.jsp?id_exam=E170907095612NA:72:15)
at http://localhost:8080/QMTM_project/tmanager/exam/q_search_ok.jsp:25:9
```

in qlist1_reload() method seem can not parse data on Chrome or FF

How to fix this error? thanks so much !!

Comment: The code at `<script>` element appears to be within `<head>` element, where if `qlist1_grid` selects an element, the element is not defined in `<body>` of `document`, as to code runs before elements within `<body>` exist. You can use `load` event of `window` or `DOMContentLoaded` to perform procedure when element within `<body>` are loaded.

Comment: Hi @guest271314: could you tell me about detail this, or can you modify code ?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload, http://api.jquery.com/ready/